# Navigating through several pages in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, jstl

`JSP, Servlets, MVC, JSTL`

I am working on a simple Blog app. My home page should display ten newest posts summaries.
In a `servlet` I am creating a list of `post objects` (arranged by `date`), attaching it to `request` and forwarding to appropriate `jsp` page. Now, lets say, there is (for example) 56 posts in that list.

I would like my blog home page to display first ten posts (post title,date and summary) from that list, and on the bottom of the page to have navigation section to next/previous, first/last , and by numbers tagged pages (usual concept for a blog). So, for example, if there is 56 posts in a list, there will be 6 pages (on last page 6 posts). And if I click on number 2, post summaries from 11-20 will display.

I know how to extract/read data from list in a request scope, using `JSTL`. But how to approach to implementing navigating concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of depends on how you get your `List` of 56 posts. You would separate your results into pages of a certain size, say 10.

You could use request parameters to indicate which page to get. The default, for example would be

```
http://yourhost/app/news
```

and that would give you the first page. This would be equivalent to

```
http://yourhost/app/news?page=1
```

Then you could specify another page

```
http://yourhost/app/news?page=2
```

And you would then have to get a `sublist` from your `List` that starts at index

```
(pageValue - 1) * sizeOfAPage
```

and only return those. This would not be done in a JSP, but in an actual `Servlet`.

Comment: Well, in servlet I am reading post data from database, using DAO and JPQL: `List<Post> posts = postDao.getNewestPosts();` and in `Dao` object: `Query q = em.createNamedQuery("getNewestPosts");
  List<Post> resultList = (List<Post>) q.getResultList();` where `getNewestPosts` is: `SELECT p FROM Post p ORDER BY p.date DESC` . You suggest to make a list of sublists in servlet? (i am not sure i have understood your idea)

Comment: @Wlad If you are getting it from database, you don't need to load the whole thing. Use the SQL `LIMIT` ([mysql example](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)) to select the start index and the number of elements.

Comment: @Wlad You're welcome. You might be interested in playing around with firebug and stackoverflow's paging technique. Go to the questions page and go through the page links at the bottom and look at the request parameters.

Comment: Yes, Firebug looks like very useful tool. But, currently I am using Chrome and Chrome has its own page inspecting tool: Tools->Developer Tools. I believe it offers similar things as Firebug in Firefox.

Comment: @Wlad Yes, you can also press F12 to open it :)